# Javascript mocking framework - Jack example

Tags: javascript, mocking

I'm currently having troubles integrating Jack into my QUnit.  Besides from not knowing where to start, I'm also confused on how to actually use it (Jack).  There aren't a great deal of examples on the web so I was wondering if anyone who have experience in using Jack to mock AJAX calls/general Javascript can show me an example or two?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QUnit integration has been added to Jack recently.

Check out introduction examples here: http://github.com/keronsen/jack